# Calculating best fit geographies in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a query to find the best fit areas within a larger area. The definition of best fit is when the centroid of the small area is within the large area as follows:

```
select p.id as parent_area_id, c.id as child_area_id
from fog.area p
inner join fog.area c on ST_CONTAINS(p.shape, ST_CENTROID(c.shape))
inner join fog.area_type_group_flattened gc on gc.child_type_id = c.type_id
inner join fog.area_type_group_flattened gp on gp.child_type_id = p.type_id
inner join fog.area_type_hierarchy h on h.parent_type_id = gp.parent_type_id and h.child_type_id = gc.parent_type_id
where p.id = :parent and c.type_id != :excludingchildtype
```

which returns 180 rows in 28s.

I have a gist index on the shape column which is of type geometry. If I replace `ST_CONTAINS` with `_ST_CONTAINS` it takes the same amount of time, suggesting it doesn't use the index, or that its usage doesn't have much effect. The table with the geometry column contains 244,325 rows, so is not massive.

If I replace `ST_CONTAINS` with `c.shape && p.shape` it returns 395 rows in 280ms. So the performance is much better but it returns too many rows.

I thought I could join using `&&` then use `ST_CONTAINS` in the where clause, so that the expensive part would run on a small result set, but that took 39s.

Is there a good way I can improve the performance of this query without changing the results? Or a similar technique that would be largely the same but much faster?

Postgres version is 9.4.4

**explain analyze**

```
Nested Loop  (cost=287.00..21510.84 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=13067.916..75160.246 rows=135 loops=1)
  Join Filter: ((t1.child_type_id = p.type_id) AND (p.shape && st_centroid(c.shape)) AND _st_contains(p.shape, st_centroid(c.shape)))
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2933423
  ->  Index Scan using area_pkey on area p  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8633) (actual time=0.123..0.125 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = 246420)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=286.58..21376.31 rows=467 width=8633) (actual time=2.339..46664.858 rows=2933558 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=286.16..288.61 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2.172..63.684 rows=198 loops=1)
              Join Filter: (h.parent_type_id = t1.parent_type_id)
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 7862
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=143.06..143.07 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.963..1.073 rows=62 loops=1)
                    Group Key: t1.parent_type_id, t1.child_type_id
                    CTE types
                      ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..135.70 rows=199 width=8) (actual time=0.043..0.448 rows=66 loops=1)
                            ->  Seq Scan on area_type area_type_1  (cost=0.00..2.49 rows=49 width=4) (actual time=0.040..0.087 rows=50 loops=1)
                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.14..12.92 rows=15 width=8) (actual time=0.075..0.112 rows=8 loops=2)
                                  Hash Cond: (t_1.child_type_id = g_1.parent_type_id)
                                  ->  WorkTable Scan on types t_1  (cost=0.00..9.80 rows=490 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.032 rows=33 loops=2)
                                  ->  Hash  (cost=1.06..1.06 rows=6 width=8) (actual time=0.057..0.057 rows=16 loops=1)
                                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                        ->  Seq Scan on area_type_group_member g_1  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=6 width=8) (actual time=0.019..0.035 rows=16 loops=1)
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.62..7.36 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.223..0.884 rows=62 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: (t1.child_type_id = t2.id)
                          ->  CTE Scan on types t1  (cost=0.00..3.98 rows=199 width=8) (actual time=0.046..0.579 rows=66 loops=1)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=2.61..2.61 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.146..0.146 rows=46 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2kB
                                ->  Seq Scan on area_type t2  (cost=0.00..2.61 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.016..0.094 rows=46 loops=1)
                                      Filter: (COALESCE(is_group, B'0'::bit(1)) = B'0'::bit(1))
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 4
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=143.09..145.50 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.026..0.512 rows=130 loops=62)
                    Hash Cond: (h.child_type_id = gc.parent_type_id)
                    ->  Seq Scan on area_type_hierarchy h  (cost=0.00..2.01 rows=101 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.103 rows=103 loops=62)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=143.08..143.08 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1.116..1.116 rows=62 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3kB
                          ->  Subquery Scan on gc  (cost=143.06..143.08 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.874..1.047 rows=62 loops=1)
                                ->  HashAggregate  (cost=143.06..143.07 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.872..0.931 rows=62 loops=1)
                                      Group Key: t1_1.parent_type_id, t1_1.child_type_id
                                      CTE types
                                        ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..135.70 rows=199 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.388 rows=66 loops=1)
                                              ->  Seq Scan on area_type  (cost=0.00..2.49 rows=49 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.052 rows=50 loops=1)
                                              ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.14..12.92 rows=15 width=8) (actual time=0.065..0.103 rows=8 loops=2)
                                                    Hash Cond: (t.child_type_id = g.parent_type_id)
                                                    ->  WorkTable Scan on types t  (cost=0.00..9.80 rows=490 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.030 rows=33 loops=2)
                                                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.06..1.06 rows=6 width=8) (actual time=0.039..0.039 rows=16 loops=1)
                                                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                                          ->  Seq Scan on area_type_group_member g  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=6 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.018 rows=16 loops=1)
                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.62..7.36 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.153..0.797 rows=62 loops=1)
                                            Hash Cond: (t1_1.child_type_id = t2_1.id)
                                            ->  CTE Scan on types t1_1  (cost=0.00..3.98 rows=199 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.523 rows=66 loops=1)
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=2.61..2.61 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.114..0.114 rows=46 loops=1)
                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2kB
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on area_type t2_1  (cost=0.00..2.61 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.063 rows=46 loops=1)
                                                        Filter: (COALESCE(is_group, B'0'::bit(1)) = B'0'::bit(1))
                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 4
        ->  Index Scan using fki_area_area_type_fkey on area c  (cost=0.42..21004.21 rows=8349 width=8633) (actual time=6.507..173.256 rows=14816 loops=198)
              Index Cond: (type_id = gc.child_type_id)
              Filter: (type_id <> 7)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 2282
Planning time: 9.831 ms
Execution time: 75160.936 ms
```

Comment: Please post the explain analyze of the query.

Comment: Also please see the definition of `ST_CONTAINS`, it uses the `~` operator so `&&` probably won't perform better.

Comment: @JakubKania I've added the explain analyze

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question with a workaround, but not accepting as it feels like a hack. Hoping for a better answer.

By using a subquery with `offset 0` at the end the subquery will be evaluated first. Then `ST_CONTAINS`, which is the expensive part, runs on a much smaller set of data. This was based on advice at http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/hinting_at_postgresql/.

```
select parent_area_id, child_area_id from
    (select p.id as parent_area_id, c.id as child_area_id, p.shape, st_centroid(c.shape) as centroid
    from fog.area p
    inner join fog.area c on p.shape && c.shape
    inner join fog.area_type_group_flattened gc on gc.child_type_id = c.type_id
    inner join fog.area_type_group_flattened gp on gp.child_type_id = p.type_id
    inner join fog.area_type_hierarchy h on h.parent_type_id = gp.parent_type_id and h.child_type_id = gc.parent_type_id
    where p.id = :parent and c.type_id != :excludingchildtype offset 0) sq
where ST_CONTAINS(shape, centroid)
```

This runs in < 1s